# how do I load debug symbols for Android Froyo (using Eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, debug-symbols

I need to set a break point in code that is handling an exception inside Froyo.  I am using Eclipse and have built a local copy (not customized) of Froyo so it should line up for my device.  Is there a way to tell ADB and/or Eclipse to load symbols so I can step into the code?

Comment: Good point ... how do I tell?  I assume it is the layer within Dalvik that would be native - correct??  So, I think my issue is still in Java - e.g., the ContentProvider or Service but not below that layer.

Comment: I tried "locate source" when Eclipse debugger presented that button and browsed to the code, but that did not work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to download android-2.2-froyo-src.zip, there are a couple sites here that are mirroring it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=979#c90

See how to use it here:
http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Comment: I have not had a chance to follow-up on this ... I followed the path and it makes sense like it should work, however, I got side tracked to other priorities.  I will try to award later this week.

Comment: Some of the references are just vague enough to provide a puzzling challenge, but I now have the source code to Froyo.  Hopefully, when I have some time, I will add to this post the steps I took to clarify the existing information.  -- Thanks @marc